# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder SBT Scala

Tags: java, scala, logging, playframework, sbt

I have ***build.sbt*** file:

```
name := """test"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.12.6"

val loggingDependencies = Seq(
"com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.+",
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3",
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % "1.+"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
...
"org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.8.0-beta1",
"org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.8.0-beta1",
)
```

After I add this dependence

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

I got an error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
```

All advices didn't help at all! What's wrong with it!

Comment: Your log dependencies are different versions.

Comment: @SamOrozco which versions and where?

Comment: My bad I was looking at the imports above.

Comment: Try `sbt clean` then building.

Comment: @SamOrozco didn't help

Comment: When do you get the error - when running which command in console? Or are you seeing this in an IDE?

Comment: @Nio got this error while **sbt run**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These versions aren't compatible, see https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#changesInVersion18 and https://logback.qos.ch/news.html. If you want Logback 1.2.3, you need SLF4J 1.7.x, if you want unstable SLF4J 1.8, you need (also unstable) Logback 1.3.x.

```
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3",
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % "1.+"
```

Having different versions for `logback-classic` and `logback-core` also doesn't make sense to me.

The final problem is having both `slf4j-simple` and `logback` in dependencies.

EDIT: Play [uses Logback on its own if not disabled explicitly](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SettingsLogger#Using-a-Custom-Logging-Framework), so it already will have some Logback and SLF4J versions in dependencies, and you override that SLF4J with an incompatible version (and add `slf4j-simple` which can't be used together with Logback). Either remove your dependencies or follow the linked documentation if you want to override what Play does.

Comment: with out **lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)** all works fine with this settings. But I try your answer -> doesn't help

Comment: Are you actually using `loggingDependencies` anywhere?

Comment: this links helped me! Thanks a lot